# confirdence interval and standard deviation in percentage using excel

Tags: excel, standards, standard-deviation, confidence-interval

I have the following data:

```
Total number of tasks / number of tasks with error / overall error rate
8   2   25%
25  4   16%
48  7   15%
8   1   13%
```

How do I find the standard deviation of percentage of overall error rate, its mean and confidence intervals in excel? I want to look at % error rate and how it will change.

Thank you for your support

Comment: Please support yourself first before you expect others to do so.

Comment: Last 8 hours is too much. this is just sample data

Comment: So what did you try in the last 8 hours?

Comment: Your data did not attach.  What have you tried?

Comment: -1 for what? I need your advice. Let me attach the same data. I know how to calculate SD and CI with numbers but I am not sure about overall percentage. I will add sample

Comment: I added four rows in text.

Comment: Potential Answer but it is not in percentage, therefore I am lost. I am not sure if I am doing it correctly:   Alpha value (for confidence interval) 0.05 
Count 9  
Mean 0.17    
Mean LCL 0.1  
Mean UCL 0.24  
Variance 0.01  
Standard Deviation 0.09  
Mean Standard Error 0.03  
Minimum 0.07  
Maximum 0.4  
Range 0.33  
Sum 1.52  
Sum Standard Error 0.28  
Total Sum Squares 0.33  
Adjusted Sum Squares 0.07  
Geometric Mean 0.15  
Harmonic Mean 0.14  
Mode 0.16

Answer (score 0):

Alpha value (for confidence interval)   0.05 Count  9 Mean  0.17 Mean LCL   0.1 Mean UCL    0.24 Variance   0.01 Standard Deviation 0.09 Mean Standard Error    0.03 Minimum    0.07 Maximum    0.4 Range   0.33 Sum    1.52 Sum Standard Error 0.28 Total Sum Squares  0.33 Adjusted Sum Squares   0.07 Geometric Mean 0.15 Harmonic Mean  0.14 Mode   0.16